# PhpStorm run command to upload to server

Tags: ssh, command, phpstorm

When I complete the project I use ssh login to the server and git pull it.
Commands like this:

```
ssh root@100.10.10.10
cd ./httpdoc/project/name
git pull
```

Does PhpStorm has any tool to run all these commands as one action?

Comment: My crystall ball says that you use Settings.../Tools/External Tools. Is this correct ? If so, you can create .sh or .bat file with all these commands and place in to your repository.

Comment: 1) General concept: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm 2) Remote (SSH) specific: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools

Answer (score 1):

With PHPStorm you can use Git in a same location that edit this. As a result that you don't necessary to request code modification in server-side (development not production environment) with `git pull`

as a matter of fact you must using synchronization tool in PHPStorm for sending code modification in your delivery and executing location.

By constrast, use git in bash command is good but not very efficient because you don't access to functionality with PHPStorm tool git implementation (compare, difference, resolve conflict, history etc...).

You must delivery your code also in development environment